# Special dictionary to NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift, dictionary, nsuserdefaults

So I have a

```
var userPlaces = [Dictionary<String, String>()]
```

Dictionary, with a sample data of

```
userPlaces.append(["name":"Schule", "subname":"Wien", "lat":"48.203015", "lon":"16.374419" ])
```

and I would like to save it in NSUserDefaults.StandarUserDefaults().
I already tried with .setObjectForKey, and .setDictionaryForKey, but when I try to regain it with .objectForKey, it gives an error "Cannot assign value of type 'AnyObject?' to type '[Dictionary]'"
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried defining userPlaces as [[String:String]]? The outer square brackets for the array and the inner ones for the dictionary type definition.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it will solve the problem:

```
userPlaces = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("YourKey") as! [Dictionary< String, String >]
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

you have to cast the object.

```
[Dictionary] dict = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults().objectForKey("blah") as! [Dictionary]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a go tomorrow